# Intuitive meaning of topology axioms

Tags: general-topology

Can someone explain, why ,intuitively, the axioms of topology regarding open sets are the way they are? (i.e. that the infinite union of open sets must be open, and that the finite intersection of open sets is again open)?

How do these axioms "respect" out notion of "nearness"?

Thanks

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets

Comment: I think, historically the concept of *neighborhood* was developed first, using filters on each point, but later it turned out that it's equivalent to the approach when open sets are given primaririly. And the axioms for the open set concept are much simpler.

Comment: To expand on @Berci's point, in a lot of applications the definition of topology used boils down to a definition of what the neighborhood bases are anyway.  And the language of filters also allows you to naturally talk about limits that would be awkward to express directly in terms of a full topology on some space - for example, $\lim_{\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert \to \infty} f(\mathbf{x})$ for some $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks @jkabrg for the reference. It was what I was looking for. Thanks Berci since it helps to know how ideas were initially formulated

Answer (score 1):

The intuition behind this definition becomes apparent after exposure to basic results in analysis. You study calculus and analysis in $\mathbb R^n,$ then later metric spaces, and eventually it becomes clear that continuity can be defined without reference to a specific metric. This is a weird and cool realization at first. But without some good background in more concrete settings, students seeing the modern definition of a topological space are likely to be dazed and confused, and possibly in search of a different major.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this is no what I asked. My question was, assuming that topology is all about measuring some generic concept of "nearness", how the particular axiomatic description based on open sets can be explained intuitively. I believe that the discussion of the question that @jkabrg mentioned, has the information (or some of the information) I was looking for